# Customize contact form in HR module- Odoo v10

Tags: odoo-10

I am trying to insert values into the applicant profile (equivalent to a Lead) from the contact form which is filled by the candidate itself. I added a new field in the contact form (for example, the surname of the candidate) like follows:

```xml
<div class="form-group form-field o_website_form_required_custom">

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 text-right">

        <label class="control-label" for="x_surname">Your surname</label>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-8">

        <input type="text" class="form-control o_website_form_input" name="x_surname" required=""/>

    </div>

</div>
```

At the same time, I created the field x_surname on the Odoo backend. But when the applicant fills the form, every predefined field  (name, email, phone...) is well inserted but not the surname that I created.

I left here two images that reflect the issue:

[image: The form modified]

When the candidate fills the form, "Apellidos" should be filled as well, but it appears at the bottom:
[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what can be missing?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Check your XML form view, you have to add it explicitly to the form

Comment: What do you mean by adding it explicitly to the form? Isn't what I did in the first picture?

Comment: The first form (an HTML form) it's a QWEB form of the "website" module that you need to edit it by adding your new input that will be binded to the new field, so to customize the disposition of your field in the view you need to edit the form view that will show the record

Comment: That was done as well, I forgot to add that screenshot to the main comment. Take A look on that (it's the last picture) where you can see how I added the field to the form view.